How to find endomorphism ring of an isogenous elliptic curve
I have a supersingular elliptic curve $E$ with a known endomorphism ring $\operatorname{End}(E)$. I'd like to find an isogeny $\varphi: E \rightarrow E'$, and by Deuring correspondence I know the corresponding ideal $I_{\varphi}$ in quaternion algebra. How could I find the endomorphism ring of $E'$ in this case?

What do you mean by "finding" the endomorphism ring? Is it enough to determine the isomorphism type (e.g. as a set of elements in the quaternion algebra containing $\text{End}(E)$), or do you need some an explicit description of the endomorphisms generating $\text{End}(E')$ (e.g. rational functions in the coordinates of $E'$)? And likewise, what data do we have about each of $\text{End}(E)$, $\varphi$, and $I_\varphi$?

For a preliminary answer: working in the quaternion algebra $B$, if $\text{End}(E)$ is the right-order of $I_\varphi$ (the set of all $\alpha\in B$ such that if $f\in I_\varphi$ then $f\cdot\alpha \in I_\varphi$) then $\text{End}(E')$ will be isomorphic to the left-order of $I_\varphi$ (the set of all $\alpha\in B$ such that if $f\in I_\varphi$ then $\alpha \cdot f \in I_\varphi$). These are not equal because $B$ is not commutative. So if you're given $I_\varphi$ as a subset of $B$ then it's quite straightforward to compute a ring isomorphic to $\text{End}(E')$.

Your formulation is unclear to me. What is given to you as input? $I_\varphi$? $E'$? It makes a big difference. Could you please clarify?

I have an elliptic curve $E$ and I know it's endomorphism ring. For example: $E: y^2 = x^3 + x$ over $\mathbb{F}_p,~p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. It is known that the endomorphism ring is isomorphic to the following order $\mathcal{O}0 = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}i \oplus \mathbb{Z} \frac{i+j}{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}\frac{1+k}{2}$. Then I choose some ideal $I{\varphi}$ which is equal to an isogeny $\varphi: E \rightarrow E'$ (according to Deuring correspondence) and find it. I'd like to understand how, in this case, I could find the endomorphism ring of $E'$ using the information above.

So the known parameters are: $E(\mathbb{F}_p), E',  \operatorname{End}(E) \cong \mathcal{O}0, \varphi: E \rightarrow E', I{\varphi}$. I'd like to find $\operatorname{End}(E')$.

Then the answer is in Jonathan Love's second comment: $\mathrm{End}(E')$ is the left order of $I_\varphi$.

Moving this from a comment to an answer since it seems that this might be what you're looking for. I'm also using this opportunity to switch right vs left - it is just a convention (do you define the multiplication $a\cdot b$ in the quaternion algebra to correspond to the composition $a\circ b$ or $b\circ a$ in the endomorphism ring) but in my comment I used the less natural choice. In what follows $a\cdot b$ corresponds to $a\circ b$.
Let $B$ be the unique quaternion algebra ramified at $p$ and $\infty$.
The endomorphism ring $\text{End}(E)$ is isomorphic to some maximal order $\mathcal{O}\subseteq B$. To any isogeny $\varphi:E\to E'$ we can associate a left $\mathcal{O}$-ideal $I_\varphi\subseteq \mathcal{O}$ as the image of $\text{Hom}(E',E)$ in $\mathcal{O}$ under the pullback map $\psi\mapsto \psi\circ\varphi$. Note that this is indeed a left $\mathcal{O}$-ideal because if $\alpha\in\text{End}(E)$ and $\psi\circ\varphi\in I_\varphi$ then $(\alpha\circ \psi)\circ\varphi\in I_\varphi$.
Given this setup, $\text{End}(E')$ is isomorphic to the right order $\mathcal{O}'$ of $I_\varphi$. In fact, we have an explicit isomorphism $\text{End}(E')\to\mathcal{O}'$ given by
$$\beta\mapsto \frac{1}{\deg\varphi}(\phi^\vee\circ\beta\circ\phi).$$
To see that $\mathcal{O}'$ is indeed a right order, if $\beta\in\text{End}(E')$ and $\psi\circ\phi\in I_\varphi$ then
$$(\psi\circ\phi)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\deg\varphi}(\phi^\vee\circ\beta\circ\phi)\right)=\frac{1}{\deg\phi}(\psi\circ \varphi\circ\varphi^\vee\circ\beta\circ\varphi)=(\psi\circ\beta)\circ\varphi\in I_\varphi$$
showing that $I_\varphi$ is closed under multiplication by elements of $\mathcal{O}'$ on the right.
To summarize: if you are given a maximal order $\mathcal{O}\simeq \text{End}(E)$, and a left $\mathcal{O}$-ideal $I_\varphi$ corresponding to $\varphi:E\to E'$, then you can recover $\text{End}(E')$ up to isomorphism by computing the right order of $I_\varphi$, that is, the set of all elements $b\in B$ such that $I_\varphi b\subseteq I_\varphi$.
One possible reference is John Voight's Quaternion Algebras Section 42.2.
